# User(Serializable) must not be accessed before initialization symfony

Tags: symfony

When i try to connect as a user (my user entity implement UserInterface), i always get this error:

> Typed property Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException::$user must not be accessed before initialization
> At: D:\cours\symfony\blog\vendor\symfony\security-core\Exception\AccountStatusException.php:45

So i implement **Serializable** like someone says it here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/38274#issuecomment-697231222 like this:

```
public function serialize(): array {
    return ['id' => $this->getId(), 'email' => $this->getEmail(), 'password' => $this->getPassword(), 'roles' => $this->getRoles()];//FIXME ajouter rôle?
}
public function unserialize($serialized): void {
    list($this->id, $this->name, $this->email, $this->roles) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

But i still get "User must not be accessed before initialization".  So maybe implementing \Serializable is the old way to do it (from 2020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to update all my bundle. Like my last edit suggested: Somes of my bundles was too old.